# Java drawLine not working with variables

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a program where a user can draw a line in a GUI by clicking on the start point of the line, dragging the mouse to the end point, and releasing it. I do not want the line to show on the screen while they are dragging, so I'm using a MouseListener.

I have created a separate class called LineInner that handles all of the MouseListener functions and have determined that it functions as intended.

This is the class where my problem resides:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class NotMSPaint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
        LineInner in =new LineInner();
        window.addMouseListener(in);

        while ( in .x1 == -1 || in.y1 == -1 || in.x2 == -1 || in.y2 == -1) {
            //pauses program until the user clicks the window
        }

        int x1 = in.x1; //variable declarations
        int y1 = in.y1;
        int x2 = in.x2;
        int y2 = in.y2;
        System.out.println(x1 + " " + y1 + " " + x2 + " " + y2);

        window.getContentPane().add(new JComponent() //problem spot
        {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                System.out.println("paint");
                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I set x1, y1, x2, and y2 to numbers such as 0 or 100 in the part I labeled variable declarations, then the line is drawn at those coordinates as intended.

When I take in variables from the MouseListener (in.x1, in.y1, etc.), the println statement shows that the coordinates are assigned to the variables as intended. When the program is run as shown above, the paint method is never entered and the line is never drawn.

> Why does it run when I assign numbers to the variables, but not run when the MouseListener assigns values to the same variables ?

Comment: Without having those int variables as `final` can you reference them inside that anonymous JComponent?

Comment: Also, it would be useful to see your MouseListener class. You can read about making a [mcve] for more information.

Comment: You're violating the threading rules of Swing by manipulating swing components from the main thread instead of the event dispatch thread. You also have a busy loop checking for your variables instead of using an event to start painting when the user clicks. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html. And read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html. And finally, you must override paintComponent(), not paint().

Comment: You might want to review https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html and other basic Swing tutorials in the series. It looks like you're missing some of the basic concepts (event driven programming, custom painting, components, etc)

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks). Also `JComponent` in _not_ opaque by default.